# Nix-shell: llvm clang based cross-compilation with llvm-libc for static linkage, never finds libc "-lc"

Tags: clang, llvm, cross-compiling, libc, nix

my goal is to setup an `shell.nix` for C and C++ cross-compiling using llvm's clang and it's corresponding libc and libc++ for static linking.

With following `hello.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf ("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I try to have a nix-shell setup for cross-compile from linux to aarch64 using llvm clang compiler stack in static linkage mode, using llvm's libc.

Therefore i was able to setup an working environment (at least for shared linking) with the shell.nix:

```hs
# https://nix.dev/tutorials/cross-compilation.html#developer-environment-with-a-cross-compiler
let
  nixpkgs = fetchTarball "https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable/nixexprs.tar.xz";
  pkgs = (import nixpkgs {}).pkgsCross.aarch64-multiplatform;

  llvmPkgs = pkgs.llvmPackages_17;
  stdenv = llvmPkgs.stdenv;
  mkShell = pkgs.mkShell.override { inherit stdenv; };
in
#https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Using_Clang_instead_of_GCC
llvmPkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "clang-nix-shell";
  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [
    pkg-config
    file
  ];
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
     zlib
    #  glibc.static
  ];
}
```

`nix-shell --run '$CC --version'` correctly reports to see a clang v17

`nix-shell --run '$CC hello.c -o hello'` correctly compiles to an aarch64 dynamically linked file

### **Problem:**

When i now go for static linkage with:
`nix-shell --run '$CC hello.c -o hello -static'`

i get the error that libc "-lc" is not found:

```bash
/nix/store/kvl0lyl8b4in5222x5gc3v33pkhzd76m-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-binutils-2.40/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lc: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can fix it by adding `glibc.static` to `buildInputs`, but in my eyes is this not correct, since it uses than the gnu-libc instead of llvm's libc. I tried in contrast to add all llvmPackages sub-packages to `buildInputs`:

```
     llvmPkgs.libcxx
     llvmPkgs.libcxxabi
     llvmPkgs.libunwind
     llvmPkgs.stdenv
     llvmPkgs.libllvm
     llvmPkgs.libcxxStdenv
     llvmPkgs.libcxxStdenv
     llvmPkgs.libclc
     llvmPkgs.compiler-rt-libc
     llvmPkgs.bintools
```

but non of them did fix it.

What am i missing here? Shouldn't exactly llvmPkgs.libcxx or llvmPkgs.libclc exactly provide the necessary library here?